# Combine timestamped data from multiple sources in single dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I try to combine timestamped data (milliseconds, synchronized) from different sources/files into a single pandas dataframe. Since the sensors I used have different sampling rate, the result will look something like this:

```
timestamp    value1    value2    value3
0            111       5         NaN
3            NaN       6         89
7            Nan       7         NaN
10           123       8         92
11           NaN       9         NaN
14           NaN       10        63
20           150       11        NaN
```

Since I know the total timespan I can create one big empty dataframe with one row per millisecond, then crawl through all the files updating cell by cell, and finally remove all rows that do not contain any data - yet I think there should be a more elegant solution that I unfortunately didn't manage to find yet.

Could you give me a hint how to tackle the problem, maybe there is even a tutorial available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ordering according to the times_tamp is what you are looking means,
create a master DataFrame , append all the sensor specific dataframes into master dataframe and sort the values on time_stamp column. Treat the null values later

Code would look something like this.

```
#Sensor 1 Data in df1
#Assuming columns in df1 similar to df2 
#say time_stamp,sensor_type, Val1,Val2
#sensor 2 Data in df2
#Decalare a masterDF
masterDF = pd.DataFrame()
masterDF =masterDF.append(df1)
masterDF =masterDF.append(df1)
masterDF =masterDF.sort_values(by = ['time_stamp'], ascending=True)
#if you was to order by both time_stamp and sensor_type, use 
#by = ['time_stamp','sensor_type']
#Older pandas version use below
# masterDF = masterDF.sort(columns=['time_stamp'],  ascending=True)
```

Hope it resolves, please let me know...

Comment: Unfortunately, every log provides different columns, yet this can be mitigated quite easily with some copy-and-pasting. Not super elegant, but looping column names is waaaay faster than looping datasets!